# jquery returns an error after i make changes to Kendo UI Grid Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid that I use to return a Grid that has check boxes in each rows.
The purpose of those check boxes is to add the Balance amount of each row that has a checked check box and process the total Balance amount after I press a button.

Here is how I do it:

```
function getData() {
return  [
    { accountNumber: "28495", transactionNumber: "2440", TransType: "INV", TransReferenceNumber: "11867115", transactionDate: "6/18/2013", transactionDebitAmount: "1920.20", openBalance: "1920.20", discountAmount: "93.60", discountApplied: "0.00", dueDate: "8/17/2013", paymentApplied: "0.00" },
    { accountNumber: "12495", transactionNumber: "1430", TransType: "INV", TransReferenceNumber: "11867225", transactionDate: "1/18/2011", transactionDebitAmount: "27620.20", openBalance: "1920.20", discountAmount: "111.60", discountApplied: "0.00", dueDate: "2/12/2013", paymentApplied: "0.00" },
    { accountNumber: "18495", transactionNumber: "1440", TransType: "INV", TransReferenceNumber: "11867115", transactionDate: "5/9/2013", transactionDebitAmount: "13320.20", openBalance: "1920.20", discountAmount: "93.60", discountApplied: "0.00", dueDate: "8/17/2013", paymentApplied: "0.00" }
             ];
}



 var grid;
 var dataSource;
 var data;

function drawInvoiceTable() {
    invoiceTable = $('#invoiceGrid').kendoGrid({
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        dataSource: {
            data: getData(),
            pageSize: 10,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: 'test',
                    fields: {
                        active: false
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
             { template: "<input type='checkbox' id='chkInvoices' class='invoiceDisplay' name='chkInvoices' #= active ? checked='checked' : '' #/>", width: 30 },
            { field: 'accountNumber', title: 'Account', attributes: { 'class': 'accountnumber' }, sortable: true },
            { field: 'transactionDate', title: 'Trans Date', attributes: { 'class': 'transdate' }, width: 100, sortable: true },
            { field: 'TransType', title: 'Type', attributes: { 'class': 'transType' }, width: 60, sortable: true },
            { field: 'TransReferenceNumber', title: 'Reference Number', attributes: { 'class': 'refnumber' }, width: 135, sortable: true },
            { field: 'transactionDebitAmount', title: 'Amount', attributes: { 'class': 'amount' }, width: 90, sortable: true },
            { field: 'openBalance', title: 'Balance', width: 90, attributes: { 'class': 'balance' }, template: '#= kendo.format("{0:p}", openBalance) #', sortable: true },
            { field: 'discountAmount', title: 'Discount', format: "{0:c}", attributes: { 'class': 'discount', 'data-format': 'c' }, width: 90, sortable: false },
            { field: 'discountApplied', title: 'Discount Applied', width: 95, attributes: { 'class': 'discapplied' }, sortable: false },
            { field: 'paymentApplied', title: 'Payment Applied' , width: 95, attributes: { 'class': 'paymentapplied' }, sortable: false },
            { field: 'discountDate', title: 'Discount Date', attributes: { 'class': 'discountDate' } },
            { field: 'dueDate', title: 'Due Date', width: 90, sortable: true }            
        ]
    });

    grid = $('#invoiceGrid').data('kendoGrid');
    dataSource = grid.dataSource;
    data = dataSource.data();
    }

$('.invoiceDisplay').on('change', function(e) {
    var idx = $(e.target).closest('tr').prevAll().length;
    var currentRow = data[idx];
    if(currentRow.active) {
        return;
    }
    var temp = currentRow.transactionDebitAmount;

    currentRow.set('active', true);
    currentRow.set('transactionDebitAmount', "0.00");
    currentRow.set('paymentApplied', temp);
    $("input[type='text']").val(temp);
});
```

I do more operation but to give you an idea, look at this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JFy2C/4/)

After I click the checkbox it goes through the code fine, then in jquery the following error is returned:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me on firefox.  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome! and jquery 1.8. I notice that in the fiddle the change event handler only happens once! In my code the handlers happen as many times as I check the checbox but get the same exception on the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$('#invoiceGrid').on('change', '.invoiceDisplay', function (e) { ... });
```

What I think happens is that you are adding a click handler to each individual `.invoiceDisplay` checkbox, but when you `.set()` the value of some of the data item properties, it triggers a `change` event on the `DataSource`. This causes the Grid to refresh to display the updated data, which recreates the row HTML elements, and looses the click handlers (since they are new elements).

The new JavaScript above adds a single click handler to the `#invoiceGrid` element, and has a sub selector to only run for `.invoiceDisplay` items, but you don't loose the click handler since it is on the grid itself.