# Kendo UI Editor : nodeName undefined in jQuery 2.0+

Tags: kendo-ui, jquery-2.0

Using `Kendo UI`'s awesome `kendoEditor`, I am experiencing a bit of an annoying issue when coupling it with `jQuery 2.0` or higher. This starts happening as soon as I use a version of jQuery higher than `1.8`.

I have reproduced the problem here, using kendo's latest build; But basically, when you create an editor, if you try to use the **indent** functionality on the *first line*, you receive this error...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null

Is there anything I can do about this? It isn't completely 'breaking', but it sure is obnoxious.

Failing Test Available Here :

## [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/aZeneLog/1/edit)

Comment: I just seen you last edit and tested it with 1.9.1 - works fine, this is happening only if you using 2.0+ as you the title of your question states. What makes you think otherwise ?

Comment: How you looking with your issue any progress ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery returns an error after i make changes to Kendo UI Grid Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727557/jquery-returns-an-error-after-i-make-changes-to-kendo-ui-grid-data)

Answer (score 0):

Without digging deep into this issue, you should be using latest Kendo build with corresponding jQuery version which is this case is 1.9.1. and it is included in the download package. Kendo relies on features from 1.9.1, by giving it 2.0 you will face compatibility issues.

kendoui.web.2013.3.1119.open-source.zip\js\jquery.min.js

```
 /*! jQuery v1.9.1 | (c) 2005, 2012 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
```